# How to insert data to a specific table on DB when using WP ALL IMPORT

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wpallimport

first of all, sorry my english is not the best. I hope you can help me.

Im developing a Wordpress site using RnB - WooCommerce Booking & Rental Plugin. The plugin works fine. The problem comes when i try to create my products using WP ALL IMPORT from a CSV file.

This plugins has uses 2 post types for the products.

1. Products: Same as woocommerce but with a new metadata that connects to "Inventory" CPT.
2. Inventory: New post type, has the price per day range, quantity, etc (all data for renting products).

I can insert all the necesary data making 2 imports. One for Products and one for Inventory. The problems is that this plugins has a table on the data base that "connects" the inventory items to the products. (a relationship table i guess)

table image:
https://desarrollodemo.tk/bebe/tabledata.png

Table name: wpmp_rnb_inventory_product
content: (2 columns)

```
inventory product
1565      1601
```

This table just needs the inventory ID and the product ID.

WP ALL IMPORT has a hook to perform actions when a post is created/updated. http://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/advanced/action-reference/

I tryed with this

First i get the CTP Inventory id
I get this id by using this code on the Wp All Import functions, when executing the import. It takes the title from the CSV and finds the inventory with the same title, then returns the id.

```
function id_returner($title = null) {
    if ( !empty( $title ) ) {
        $ids = get_page_by_title( $title, OBJECT, 'inventory' );
        $id = $ids->ID;
        return $id;
    }
}
```

Then i tryed adding this code on the functions.php to hook this action when a post is created/saved by Wp All Import.

```
add_action('pmxi_saved_post', 'post_saved', 10, 1);

function post_saved($id) {
    $inventario = get_post_meta($id, 'id_inventario', true);
    global $wpdb;
    $table = $wpdb->prefix.'wpmp_rnb_inventory_product';
    $data = array('column1' => $inventario, 'column2' => $id);
    $format = array('%s','%d');
    $wpdb->insert($table,$data,$format);
    $my_id = $wpdb->insert_id;
}
```

But this is not working at all. I dont recieve any error message, but after the import the table is empty.

I hope you can help me!. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

You can drag & drop the `_redq_product_inventory` custom field element from the Available Data section to your export items. It should add the inventory IDs.

When you customize your import, create a new custom field, using `_redq_product_inventory` as the name, and `{_redq_product_inventory[1]}` as the value.

Here's a function to import products and inventories to the table:

```
add_action('pmxi_saved_post', 'post_saved', 10, 1);
function post_saved($product_id) {

    $inventories = get_post_meta($product_id,'_redq_product_inventory',true);

    global $wpdb;
    $table = $wpdb->prefix.'rnb_inventory_product';

    foreach($inventories as $inventory) {
        $data = array('inventory' => $inventory, 'product' => $product_id);
        $format = array('%d','%d');
        $wpdb->insert($table,$data,$format);
    }
}
```

If you delete and re-import inventories with WP All Import, their new IDs will not match with those in your products. To avoid this, you can use Tools >> Export and Tools >> Import for your inventory posts.